# Should I normalize 20 millions row x 2 column MySQL table

Tags: mysql, normalization, database-normalization

I have a MySQL table which contains 20 millions of rows and 2 columns and structure like below.

```
item_id (unsigned int[11] PK) | item_name (varchar[50]) | image_path (varchar[50])
```

Should I separate `image_path` column to another table, like

```
image_id | image_path
```

What will be performance gain /loss? Will *join* requests faster than **select *** requests for only one table on this large data set?

My database only one table for now. If I normalize it will be two.

and my requests will be like

```
SELECT items.item_name, images.image_path 
FROM items 
LEFT JOIN images on images.image_id = items.image_id
WHERE item_id = 123
```

and I'm currently using

```
SELECT item_name, image_path FROM items WHERE item_id = 123
```

another hard option for me is *MySQL Partitioning* my table with **RANGE Partitioning**

What is the best way for performance?

Comment: With respect, your question doesn't make any sense unless you show us the other tables in your database design. Please [edit] your question to show us the tables you'll use in potential `JOIN` operations.

Comment: Can you have more than one image per item? If not, then there is no point in creating another table. If yes, then you should create a separate image table. Also, if you use the same image for lots of items, then you should again consider using a separate table.

Comment: @Shadow I have no more than one image per item. Can you provide some resource for your answer?

Comment: What resource are you talking about?

Comment: Normalization through BCNF is based on functional dependencies. What functional dependencies do you think hold for the table "items"?

Comment: Introducing a surrogate key as a compact representation of a set of values has nothing to do with database normalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the query you show, you look up one row in `items` by primary key value 123, and then join to one row in `images` by primary key value.  That's two primary key value lookups, when you could have done one.

In MySQL's default storage engine, InnoDB, a `NULL` value doesn't take any storage space. So I would suggest if some of your item rows have an image_path and some don't, then just define image_path as nullable. That's bound to be better for performance.

You also ask about `PARTITION BY RANGE`. With respect, 20 million rows is not a big table.

In the databases I manage, I partitioned one table by date because it has 4.7 *billion* rows (i.e. 235x the size of your table). There are quite a few other tables that have millions of rows, but they are fine without being partitioned.

As long as you use the index or primary key when you do lookups, you should be okay.